# django-selectable app - get/save 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have an auto-complete field on my form and template.  The template is populated a ModelForm.  The lookup is based on a simple table (db.category) consisting of the primary key "id" and a text description.  I want to save the id (not the text/value).  The django-selectable docs, though better than a lot I have seen,  do not have enough detail, or robust enough examples for me (a relative newbie) to figure it out. If anyone has some examples code they could share I'd appreciate it. (I am not using the admin).  I think I'm ok with the model.py and lookup.py. Not sure about form.py or view.py.  Could be missing something on the template, but I think its ok).

Thanks.

Comment: " I think I'm ok with the model.py and lookup.py. Not sure about form.py or view.py"?  Please actually provide the code with which you're okay, so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: There is an example project in the source tree https://bitbucket.org/mlavin/django-selectable/src/ae8455162d5e/example